# Form with tinymce textarea failing to submit more than once using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, tinymce

I'm trying to submit a form using ajax while using tinymce as my textarea editor but the form is only submitting on the first instance and not working in subsequent submissions.

This is my form

```
<form action="{{action('QuizController@postQuiz', [$quiz_id])}}" method="POST"  id="quiz_form">
<textarea class=" tinymce" placeholder="Enter the question" name="m_c_question" required></textarea>
</form>
```

This is my tinymce initializer

```
 <script>
 $(function () {
tinymce.init({
    selector: "tinymce",
    statusbar: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            editor.save();
        });
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

And this is my ajax code to submit the form to the database

```
$('#quiz_form').submit(function(event) {

    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    // get the form data
    var formData = {
        'm_c_question'                  : $('textarea[name=m_c_question]').val(),
    };      

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'quiz',
        data        : formData, 
        dataType    : 'json', 
        encode      : true
    })
```

I can't seem to find the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ajax is [cached](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')

So add `cache` to the list of params

```
$.ajax({
    cache       : false,
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'quiz',
    data        : formData, 
    dataType    : 'json', 
    encode      : true
})
```

Comment: @user3714932 can you make a jsfiddle to check it?